# Monolithic to Microservices with Sharing DB

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I am trying to move slowly moving the app from Monolithic to microservices but the first step is to move to a more like microservices ready state.

I have a monolithic system SA that needs to push large amount of data to Cassandra table TB and the service SB that consumes the TB table, does that against the microservices principle?

Basically I want a large amount of data that to push to the service SB but if it pushes that via rest api that is too large and time consuming.

Answer (score 2):

Well, maybe this is an opinion based question, but I strongly believe that each microservice should execute its task as **independently** from other systems, as possible.

In your case, you should ask yourself, what happens if an attribute of the data that gets saved should be deleted from SA? Does it have consequences for SB?
Also notice, that if you heavily write and read the same data source, service SA will cause performance issues to SB and vice versa.

As regards the communication between the microservices `REST` is **not** your only option; you could also consider using `asynchronous communication - Messaging` (RabbitMQ, Kafka..), having SA as publisher and SB subscriber.

But the starting point should be:

> "Do my SA and SB need to be independently deployable and scalable from
>   each other?"

If not, there is definitely **no reason** for two services.

There is a great [Refactoring to System of Systems talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWefNT8Lb74&t=11s) from Oliver Gierke about what you need, mentioning common pitfalls and useful suggestions, that I can only recommend.
Please, also check the [database-per-service](http://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html) and the other patterns by Chris Richardson.